# Azure cosmosDB(mongoDB), how to disable the automatic indexing in a collection in GO lang or via Shell

Tags: mongodb, azure, go, azure-cosmosdb

I tried to delete the **DocumentDBDefaultIndex** manually through mongo shell and also through my GO code but it still exists. I don't want to have those default indexes lying around which would consume unnecessary space; I actually only need some _id, unique and text indexes.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the index policy for the collection? You can include/exclude any properties for indexing, as well as changing the indexing type & precision. (this is easy to do via the portal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that mongo wire protocol does not support the feature of indexing policy change. As @DavidMakogon said, please refer to the document [`How does Azure Cosmos DB index data?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies) to change the settings of indexing policy on Azure portal as the figure below, or using REST API [`Replace a Collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/replace-a-collection).

[image]

Hope it helps.